# Problems with system or exec

Tags: php, linux, scp

I'm trying to fetch a file and send a command to another server.

I'm trying to do the following:

```
system('scp root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/etc/something.conf /tmp/',$ret);
```

But the file isn't copied. If I `echo $ret` it outputs 1. If I log to the server through SSH and execute the same command it does well.

What could be wrong?

PS: The access to the other server is made with a public key stored in the server.

Comment: Try adding `2>&1` to your command and see if an error is displayed.

Comment: That's what I retreive: Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh'. Host key verification failed. 1

Comment: Your webserver has a home directory containing the private key for root on another system! Do you understand the risks here?

Comment: I don't know where it is but probabily not in the home directory

Comment: @Antonio: I was editing my comment when you posted yours. This implies that you DO NOT have the private key on the machine where it is accessible by your webserver uid - and you probably shouldn't. Particularly if you don't understand why it's not currently working.

Comment: @symcbean It's not my server... or sort of... it's a server in my office in which I was told to execute this to make some things in a php application I developed. I'm pretty nooby with Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using ssh keys to do the scp, you need to add the servers public key for the user which is running php (typically the apache user at 'www-data' for ubuntu and 'apache' for CentOS)

As for debugging, the hint from Salman A should be useful

Using a different username than root (add some user without any privileges) for this is also good advice!